# Apache beam - look back x mins from each element

Tags: python, apache-beam

I am trying to calculate the total number of transactions done by each customer in last x min.

Let's say there are a total of 3 elements, I would like to look back last 5 minutes and find the sum for each customer.

- {"event_time": 12:01, "customer": "A", "amount": 10.00} -> look up last 5 minutes (from event time 11.55 to 12.00) and sum (result: 0)
- {"event_time": 12:02, "customer": "A", "amount": 20.00} -> look up last 5 minutes (from event time 11.56 to 12.01) and sum (result: 10)
- {"event_time": 12:03, "customer": "A", "amount": 30.00} -> look up last 5 minutes (from event time 11.57 to 12.02) and sum (result: 10 + 20)

The expected output is

- {"event_time": 12:01, "customer": "A", "amount": 10.00, "sum": 0.00}
- {"event_time": 12:02, "customer": "A", "amount": 20.00, "sum": 10.00}
- {"event_time": 12:03, "customer": "A", "amount": 30.00, "sum": 20.00}

It's similar to the sliding window, but for each element instead of a timed window. Can it be done with Apache Beam?

Here is the code to create dummy data

```
import time

import apache_beam as beam

from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.transforms.combiners import MeanCombineFn, CountCombineFn

def to_unix_time(time_str: str, time_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') -> int:
  """Converts a time string into Unix time."""
  time_tuple = time.strptime(time_str, time_format)
  return int(time.mktime(time_tuple))

@beam.ptransform_fn
@beam.typehints.with_input_types(beam.pvalue.PBegin)
@beam.typehints.with_output_types(beam.window.TimestampedValue)
def CreateData(pipeline):
    return (
      pipeline
      | 'Create dummy data' >> beam.Create([
          {'TX_ID': '01', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:36:00', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'A', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '02', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:36:30', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'B', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '03', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:37:00', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'A', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '04', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:37:30', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'B', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '05', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:38:00', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'A', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '06', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:38:30', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'B', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '07', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:39:00', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'A', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '08', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:39:30', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'B', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '09', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:40:00', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'A', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '10', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:40:30', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'B', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '11', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:41:00', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'A', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '12', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:41:30', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'B', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '13', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:42:00', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'A', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '14', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:42:30', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'B', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '15', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:43:00', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'A', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '16', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:43:30', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'B', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '17', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:44:00', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'A', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '18', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:44:30', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'B', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '19', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:45:00', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'A', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
          {'TX_ID': '20', 'TX_TS': '2022-08-04 08:45:30', 'CUSTOMER_ID': 'B', 'TX_AMOUNT': 10.00},
      ])
      | 'With timestamps' >> beam.Map(
          lambda x: beam.window.TimestampedValue(x, to_unix_time(x['TX_TS']))
      )
    )
```

Things that I have tried so far:

- Used Fixed Windows

```
window_size = 60 * 5  # 5 min

beam_options = PipelineOptions(flags=[], type_check_additional='all')
with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
  (
      pipeline
      | 'Create dummy data' >> CreateData()
      | 'Fixed windows' >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(window_size))
      | 'Change to namedtuple' >> beam.Map(lambda x: beam.Row(**x))
      | 'Group By' >> beam.GroupBy('CUSTOMER_ID')
            .aggregate_field('TX_AMOUNT', sum, 'total_amount_5min')
            .aggregate_field('TX_AMOUNT', CountCombineFn(), 'tx_count_5min')
            .aggregate_field('TX_AMOUNT', MeanCombineFn(), 'average_amount_5min')
      | 'Print element info' >> beam.Map(print)
  )
```

- Used Sliding Windows

```
window_size = 60 * 5  # 5 min
window_period = 60  # 1 min

beam_options = PipelineOptions(flags=[], type_check_additional='all')
with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
  (
      pipeline
      | 'Create dummy data' >> CreateData()
      | 'Fixed windows' >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.SlidingWindows(window_size, window_period))
      | 'Change to namedtuple' >> beam.Map(lambda x: beam.Row(**x))
      | 'Group By' >> beam.GroupBy('CUSTOMER_ID')
            .aggregate_field('TX_AMOUNT', sum, 'total_amount_5min')
            .aggregate_field('TX_AMOUNT', CountCombineFn(), 'tx_count_5min')
            .aggregate_field('TX_AMOUNT', MeanCombineFn(), 'average_amount_5min')
      | 'Print element info' >> beam.Map(print)
  )
```

Both options didn't give what I want. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay. I managed to solve this using lambda functions and window end time.

The sample code can be found here (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fraudfinder/blob/main/03_feature_engineering_streaming.ipynb)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `window` functions will really help in your case since you need to have a 5 minute window for each element.

You can try to do more of a python oriented approach inside the pipeline.
EG:

```
import datetime
def convert(date_time):
    format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'  # The format
    datetime_str = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time, format)
    return datetime_str

def process(rows):   
    temp_rows = rows[1]
    result = temp_rows
    for row in temp_rows:
        search_to = convert(row['TX_TS']) - datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
        search_from = convert(row['TX_TS']) - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
         
        amounts = [row['TX_AMOUNT'] for row in temp_rows if convert(row['TX_TS'])>=search_from and convert(row['TX_TS']) <=search_to]
        sum_amounts= sum(amounts)        
        row['sum'] = sum_amounts
    return temp_rows


with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
  (
      pipeline
      | 'Create dummy data' >> CreateData()
      | beam.Map(lambda x: (x['CUSTOMER_ID'], x))
      | beam.GroupByKey()
      | beam.Map(lambda x : (process(rows=x)))
      | 'Print element info' >> beam.Map(print)
  )
```

Also you might need to do some post processing of the result as it will be grouped for each *customer id*.

Comment: Thanks so much for attempting it. I tried something similar too. I will post the answer in a while :)

Comment: @ThuYaKyaw yeah sure , I am also looking forward to see your approach.